# Transfer function of EMI filter

Tags: high-voltage, emc, passive-networks, emi-filtering

In order to define the transfer function of an EMI filter, I want  to know if I need to define the equivalent circuit in CM and in DM to calculate the total transfer function of the  filter below:

[image]

Comment: Hi Nicolas! I must admit that I don't know what "CM" and "DM" are, but that might be because English is not my native language. Why do you use the [tag:high-voltage] tag? Is there something specifically high-voltage about this circuit?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Probably CM = common mode, DM = differential mode.

Comment: Hi Nicolas. An EMI filter will contain chokes, not inductors. These will exhibit nonlinear behaviour. Trying to tackle this with filter theory may be the wrong method.

Comment: @Andreas Yes  it a chokes  just i dont find a chokes in PSIM

Comment: @Nicolas I do not know much about simulation. You may want to read though [this](http://www.intusoft.com/articles/inductor.pdf). Transfer functions are used to characterize linear time-invariant systems, so you questions title may be misleading.

Comment: Need to know exactly what the common mode chokes are and caps. Ferrite is non-linear and can only be approximated in the frequency domain. Some filter components will provide a test frequency graph, with which you could approximate a transfer function.